# Setting a cookie in javascript with an implicitly returned conditional

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, conditional-statements

**Why would this be the case?**

Trying to set a cookie using the "cookies" npm module like so...

```
if (req.query.thing === 'true') try {
    res.cookies.set('name', 2431234, {expires: moment().add(1, 'h').toDate()})
} catch(err) {
    console.log(err)
}
```

The above code works as expected but there is no need for the catch so in interest of conciseness I am trying this...

```
if (req.query.thing === 'true') res.cookies.set('name', 2431234, {expires: moment().add(1, 'h').toDate()})
```

^ This does not work. Other cookies I've set are making it through and are set to the header but this one isn't. Also any actions below this statement are not run.

I have traced the function through the cookies module and it makes it all the way through just never returns.

Want to make sure there's no error in my understanding before opening issue with npm module.

Comment: Can you post more code around this `if`? Also it's better to enclose the statement into brackets, the code will be less error-prone :)

Comment: if (req.query.thing === 'true') {res.cookies.set('name', 2431234, expires: {})}
Are you just missing brackets after if?

Comment: You need to wrap `expires: {}` in curly brackets (as an Object), otherwise neither example is valid JavaScript...

Comment: Indeed @Frxstrem is right, I would suggest the OP uses an editor with Linting, as this error would have been picked up by the Linter.  ESLint, is a good linter.

Comment: @Frxstrem

I apologize I actually mistyped the original question. Edited it to show correct and current code.

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin 

I've heard arguments from both sides as to should one line conditionals need brackets.

Most saying yes they should argue it's better because of the possibility of expanding the conditional later on and forgetting the brackets leading to a broken script. 

At this point, my company is on the side of not using the brackets as we see it as more readable and reduces superfluous characters. Also in case someone does expand the conditional we have linters that will catch the missing brackets.